# How can I export my full customers credit card information between 2 different merchant accounts

Tags: databases, pci-dss, credit-card

I am trying to find out how we can get our existing customers credit card details released from our current merchant account and transferred to our new merchant account. The new bank we are working with are happy to accept the customers and have informed me they have the correct practices in place, transfer by secure email into a secure vault within there own banking infrastructure.
However our existing Merchant account doesn't support Credit Card Data Portability, and they are trying to hold our existing customer database. If anyone can give me an insight or some advice it would be invaluable to us at the moment.

Comment: If they don't support that method, any advice given here would be attempting to bypass security mechanisms they have put in place. You, as a merchant, should not be able to extract that data directly. If the current provider does not want to be cooperative, you're probably better off looking at legal mechanisms to pursue them, but you'd need to speak to a lawyer about options there. Unfortunately, it might be that they have terms allowing their current behavior, in which case you might need to ask customers for details again.